# Extract meta description field with goquery

Tags: go, extract, meta, goquery

I'm using the [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) package to extract pieces of information from a webpage. Please see my code below. The outcome when after running the function is:

```
Description field: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15
Description field: width=device-width
Description field: THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT
```

I'm almost there, however I only want to get the meta field where the name == 'description'. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to add this extra condition to my code.

```
func ExampleScrapeDescription() {
    htmlCode :=
        `<!doctype html>
<html lang="NL">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT">
        <title>page title</title>
    </head>
    <body class="fixedHeader">
        page body
    </body>
</html>`

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader((htmlCode)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc.Find("meta").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        description, _ := s.Attr("content")
        fmt.Printf("Description field: %s\n", description)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just examine the value of the `name` attribute whether it matches `"description"`:

```
doc.Find("meta").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    if name, _ := s.Attr("name"); name == "description" {
        description, _ := s.Attr("content")
        fmt.Printf("Description field: %s\n", description)
    }
})
```

You may want to compare the value of the `name` attribute in a case insensitive manner, for that you can use [`strings.EqualFold()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#EqualFold):

```
if name, _ := s.Attr("name"); strings.EqualFold(name, "description") {
    // proceed to extract and use the content of description
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```golang
    attr, _ := doc.Find("meta[name='description']").Attr("content")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be more easier for others to understand if you added an explanation of how it works to your answer.